# Some questions about Stripe connect express

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am currently trying to use direct charges instead of destination charges (mainly because I don't want to have to cover the stripe fee's and charge backs).

My two main concerns are:

1. Does the statement_descriptor and statement_descriptor_suffix for paymentIntent override connect accounts own statement descriptions when using direct charges on a connect account? If so, would that prevent the connect users address/phone number from being exposed?
2. Is there a way to store the payment method in a platform customer when using direct charges to the connect account?

Comment: Stripe's support service is genuinely amazing. Get in contact with them, they're really quick and efficient.

Comment: Thanks! I will give them a try as well!

Comment: It will probably override once it would not make sense to simply ignore a value you are sending in the API request. On a side question: is not the overhead of the full Stripe dashboard a problem for you app? I had cases where merchants could not handle the complexity of it

Comment: Ah - I don't have anything out yet but I can see how that could be a problem. I think minimizing the need for them to go out of your app (reporting balances, alerting them in case of a charge back should ease some of that burden). I have moved onto using destination charges with connect express for my implementation (mainly since I need to save customers onto my platform instead of the connect accounts in order to save payments.